# Python virtualenv command not regonized on windows 7

Tags: windows, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am new to python please forgive me if question is silly.

I am using python version 3.4.
I have install virtualenv.
I am tryping command virtualenv env and i get response like command not found. 
Does this required any environment variable to set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its done, I just updated my `virtualenv` through `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`